# Optimizar reemplazos de string con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Paso a contar, hice mi propio buscador con `JQuery` ya que los que están o no los entendí o en realidad tengo una incompatibilidad con mi código. El tema es que necesito optimizar el reemplazo de carácteres ya que ralentiza un poco la ejecución.
Combiné `JavaScript` con `JQuery` ya que no encontré una función para esto, no sé si la abrá. 
Desde ya, el que pueda colaborar le estaré más que agradecido.

Lo que obtengo en `sugerencias` es un JSON así:

> ["Manuel_Richard", "Ricardo_Darin"]

Y a lo que lo convierto con la función `replace()` es esto:

```
<option>Manuel Richard</option>
<option>Ricardo Darin</option>
```

**index.php:**

```
<script src="../js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#inputDate").keyup(function(){
        var input=($("#inputDate").val());
        if(input.length >= 2){
        var link="search.php?term="+input;
        $.get(link, function(sugerencias){
            str = sugerencias;
            var ree0 = /"/g;
            var ree1 = /\[/g;
            var ree2 = /,/g;
            var ree3 = /\]/g;
            var ree4 = /_/g;
            var r0 = str.replace(ree0, '');
            var r1 = r0.replace(ree1, '<option>');
            var r2 = r1.replace(ree2, '</option><br><option>')
            var r3 = r2.replace(ree3, '</option>');
            var r4 = r3.replace(ree4, ' ');
            $("#sugeridos").html(r4);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: ¿La variable `sugerencias` posee es una [cadena JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON)?

Comment: Sí, mis disculpas por no aclararlo, están echas con json_encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que `sugerencias` es una [cadena JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON), podrías hacer uso de:

- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse): para convertir la cadena en un arreglo.
- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce): para convertir cada elemento del arreglo, en un `option` y obtener en una cadena con todo el `HTML`

#### Demo:

```js
function callback(sugerencias) {
  $("#sugeridos").html(
    JSON.parse(sugerencias)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return prev + `<option>${curr.replace(/_/g, ' ')}</option>`;
    }, '')
  );
}

callback('["Manuel_Richard", "Ricardo_Darin"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sugeridos"></select>
```

#### Solución completa:

```
<script src="../js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#inputDate").keyup(function() {
    var input = ($("#inputDate").val());
    if (input.length >= 2) {
      var link = "search.php?term=" + input;
      $.get(link, function(sugerencias) {
        $("#sugeridos").html(
          JSON.parse(sugerencias)
          .reduce((prev, curr) => {
            return prev + `<option>${curr.replace(/_/g, ' ')}</option>`;
          }, '')
        );
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No creo que el uso de string templates ` y arrow functions => sea lo mejor, no todos los navegadores son compatibles con esto, al no ser que traspiles tu codigo de javascript con babel u otra herramienta

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, si, en principio es cierto que no es compatible con todos los navegadores, pero los principales navegadores se actualizan solos y soportan estas nuevas herramientas. A esta altura no creo que sea beneficioso ponernos a ver que funciona y que no, porque si vamos al caso, por ejemplo, la API `JSON` tampoco funciona en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Vale buen punto ;P

Answer (score 1):

Mira ver si esto te ayuda:

```
$("#inputDate").keyup(function(){
   var input=($("#inputDate").val());
   if(input.length >= 2){
    var link="search.php?term="+input;
    $.get(link, function(sugerencias){
      //Conviertes a json lo que te devuelve el get, puedes obviar este paso si lo que devuelves es un json
      // y no un string en ese caso var json = sugerencias, o puedes cambiar sugerencias por json y no hace
      // falta la asignacion
      var json = JSON.parse(sugerencias);
      var html = "";
      //Recorro el arreglo de nombres y voy conformando el html
      json.map(function(nombre) {
        //El <br> no lo necesitas, en cambio el /n te formatea la salida mejor en cuanto a codigo
        html += "<option>"+nombre.trim().replace(/_/g, " ")+"</option>\n";
     });
     $("#sugeridos").html(html);
  });
 }
});
```